# Lightning DataTable with CaseShare - Returning User or Group Name

Tags: sharing, lightning-datatable, apex-sharing

I am using the lightning datatable in order to display the CaseShare data for a Case record within a lightning component. The feature works great however as the field UserOrGroupId on the CaseShare object is not editable I can only ever get the table to return the Id value of the user or group with which the record is shared. Below I am trying to override the value with a text value. But I am stopped as the UserOrGroupId is not editable. I have also tried to create a map of the data but was unable to get the correct data to display on my datatable.

```
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List<sObject> getCaseShareData(Id caseId){

    List<sObject> caseShareList = [Select Id, CaseId, RowCause, UserOrGroupId from CaseShare where CaseId = :caseId];

    for(sObject myCaseShare : caseShareList){

        myCaseShare.put(CaseShare.UserOrGroupId, 'Test Name');
    }


    return caseShareList;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good place to use a wrapper object, a simple Apex class that embeds the sObject you're returning (here, a `CaseShare`) along with any extra data points you want to include that aren't part of the sObject itself. It could look like this:

```
public class CaseShareWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public CaseShare share;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String displayName;
}
```

Then, your controller method can create and return a `List<CaseShareWrapper>`, setting the display name for each entity as you desire.